# How can I do to filter currency chinese character in Ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, format

I have a query.

```
 SELECT TypeID,          <==Number
    APrice as 1,         <==Currency
    Null as 2 
 FROM tblA 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT TypeID, 
    Null as 1,
    MPrice as 2          <==Currency
 FROM tblM;
```

If i tried to apply filter on [ID], i am getting chinese character on [2].
Why? Both tables are new with 5 rows for test code.

Sample database link:

```
 https://wetransfer.com/downloads/515a6bf52505af5a40b58e8949d2ffc720180411064648/6159bb
```

Open the qtrTest and press Filter Button on [ID] = 1 or 2 or 3.
You will see on [2], chinese character.

The Sample Database is new and fresh without corrupt data.

Comment: You have 2 semicolons at the end. What do you mean chinese character? Show us the filter.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Thxs @Wazz, I correct semicolons. Edit also the post.

Comment: Thxs @D-Shih, I placed a download link for a sample database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Access* preset reads setting of the default Currency symbol in the computer system.

Follow this path

> Control Panel -> Check Language and Region -> Region -> Currency

Then you can see your system default *Currency* symbol

Also you can use `Format` function to set your Currency symbol.

```
 SELECT TypeID,      
    Format ( APrice, "#,##0.00 €" ) as 1,        
    Null as 2 
 FROM tblA 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT TypeID, 
    Null as 1,
    Format(MPrice, "#,##0.00 €" ) as 2       
 FROM tblM;
```

**EDIT**

A simple way you can use `VAL` function.

It can returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type.

```
SELECT TypeID, 
Val(Format ( APrice, "#,##0.00 €" )) as 1, 
Null as 2 
FROM tblA 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TypeID, Null as 1, 
Val(Format(MPrice, "#,##0.00 €" )) as 2 
FROM tblM;
```

[VAL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/val-function-e5e1f21b-22f9-41c9-bd0a-fe55b767f603)

[Setting Default Currency](https://windowsreport.com/windows-8-currency-settings/)

[Format](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/format.php)

Comment: Thxs... I was reading and testing for 48hours to find a solution.

Comment: I am getting the number as a text. Is it possible to format it in number?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tested VAL before and it was not working with decimal numbers. Keep in mind that APrice or MPrice might have negative number, example -5.300,12. I am not care about keeping currency symbol or formatting "Standard". Just to have number with decimal. So, if APrice is 12.234,12 $, I want to have 1 to 12234,12. I am trying to export this query to excel and I am getting a mess with texts and numbers.

Comment: After hours testing, I found that my problem is the NULL. If I replace it with 0, it is working. Now, I am trying to find a way to hide 0.

Comment: Instead of Null I used a zero (since it is a currency field). In my report
I did not want zeroes showing up, I wanted Null (nothing) - so I changed my
control source for each of the fields to an iif() statement. IIf([Field] >
0, [Field]).

It works great!